# How to disable auto update on scroll of a recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, autoscroll

I am building an Ecommerce app where I need to select the quanitity on the recycleview for each items. And scrolling down after selecting the upward items , the recyclerview refreshes and put the the value 0 again.

I need a very quick solution to that as I'm hanged in an ongoing project.

```
  public void readOrders()
{
        final FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        final DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("https://kharkhowa-3b20d.firebaseio.com/items");
        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                list.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    ItemClass itemClass = dataSnapshot1.getValue(ItemClass.class);
                    assert itemClass != null;
                    assert firebaseUser != null;
                    list.add(itemClass);
                }
                Log.i("sizeeeeeeeeeeeee", String.valueOf(list));
                itemAdapter = new ItemAdapter(getApplicationContext(), list);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(itemAdapter);
                recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(recyclerView.getContext(), DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));

            }


            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
}
```

Adapter Class

```
public class ItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemAdapter.ViewHolder>{
HashMap<String, List<String>> hm = new HashMap();
Context context;
private List<ItemClass> list ;
int n, total = 0;

public ItemAdapter(Context context, List<ItemClass> list) {
    this.context = context;
    this.list = list;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.items,parent,false);
    return new ItemAdapter.ViewHolder(view);
}

@SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    // int n = 0;

        String s = "";
        final ItemClass itemClass = list.get(position);
        holder.itemName.setText(itemClass.getItemName());
        final String price = itemClass.getItemPrice();
        s = String.valueOf(n);
        holder.noOfitem.setText(s);
        holder.plus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String n1 = (String) holder.noOfitem.getText();
                int i = Integer.parseInt(n1);
                i = i + 1;
                String s1 = String.valueOf(i);
                holder.noOfitem.setText(s1);
                //n++;
                String ab = (String) holder.noOfitem.getText();
                int b = Integer.parseInt(ab);
                List<String> list = new ArrayList();
                list.add(price);
                list.add(ab);
                hm.put(itemClass.getItemName(), list);
                Log.i("hashhhhhhhhhh", hm.toString());
                if (b == 1) {
                    total = total + 1;
                    Intent intent = new Intent("custom-message");
                    intent.putExtra("total", String.valueOf(total));
                    intent.putExtra("hashmap", hm);
                    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent);
                }
            }
        });
        holder.minus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String n1 = (String) holder.noOfitem.getText();
                int i = Integer.parseInt(n1);
                if (i > 0) {
                    i = i - 1;
                    String s1 = String.valueOf(i);
                    holder.noOfitem.setText(s1);
                    String ab = (String) holder.noOfitem.getText();
                    int b = Integer.parseInt(ab);
                    List<String> list = new ArrayList();
                    list.add(price);
                    list.add(ab);
                    hm.put(itemClass.getItemName(), list);
                    Log.i("hashhhhhhhhhh", hm.toString());
                    if (b == 0) {
                        total = total - 1;
                        Intent intent = new Intent("custom-message");
                        intent.putExtra("total", String.valueOf(total));
                        intent.putExtra("hashmap", hm);
                        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent);
                    }
                    //  n--;
                }
            }
        });


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list.size();
}


public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    public TextView itemName,noOfitem,cartnext;
    public ImageView minus,plus;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        itemName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemname);
        noOfitem = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.noOfitem);
        minus = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.minus);
        plus = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.plus);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. What have you [investigated](https://solutionspirit.com/on-scrolling-recyclerview-change-values) so far?

Answer (score 0):

get `getItemCount()` then it returns actual count

```
getItemCount()
```

keep size recycleview in variable in the bigining

Comment: Thank you sir for quick responds but I haven't use any of the above method.

Comment: wait i will check

Comment: do you get getItemCount()

Comment: I don't have any problem in no of elements. In recycle with , along with item there is a textview to select the number of item that he wants to buy. Because of  autorefresh ,that number becomes 0

Comment: Hello sir, Will it work if I save the instance of the recyclerview ?